# questions about fsi

Tags: f#

1. how to change the working directory of fsi in VS.
2. how to auto load DLLs (e.g. the powerpack) at the startup of fsi.
3. how to auto open namespaces at the startup of fsi.

Thanks!

Comment: Please pose one question at a time.

Comment: These three questions are correlated, see the answers by Tomas.

Comment: Answering the three questions at once was definitely easier.

Comment: _Just a tip_; After you reset the FSI session, the current folder will be set back to the temp folder.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no direct way to specify this, but you can use the `--use:file.fsx` command line parameter, which allows you to specify an FSX file that will be loaded by F# interactive when it starts. You can specify the parameter in Tools -> Options -> F# Tools.

To do the three things you asked for, your `file.fsx` should look like this:

```
// 3. Open some namespace
open System

// 1. Change the current directory
Environment.CurrentDirectory <- "C:\\Temp"

// 2. Reference an assembly (e.g. PowerPack)
#r @"FSharp.PowerPack.dll"
```

Comment: Since `open System` is after the use of `Environment`, you'll need to use `System.Environment.CurrentDirectory`.

Answer (score 1):

See [F# Interactive Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233172(VS.100).aspx) for a description of all of the available command line options.  As detailed on that page, you can use the `-r` option to reference a particular DLL.  There aren't built-in options for the other two questions you asked, but as Tomas mentioned, you can put them into a file which you `#use`.